# How to run some processes simultaneously on ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, system

I want to verify that my computer supports virtual address.
Then I write a `.cpp` code.But I don't know how to run then simultaneously.
I use the command

```
./t &
./t
```

but it doesn't work.

My code is here:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;

int svar = 0;

   int main()
   {
    int lvar = 0;
    svar +=1;
    lvar +=1;
    sleep(10);
    printf("svar address:%x, val %d\n",&svar,svar);
    printf("lvar address:%x, val %d\n",&lvar,lvar);
   }
```

Which comes from OS principals and practices.

The running result of `t.cpp` is:

```
svar address:bc0f9014, val 1
svar address:afef5014, val 1
lvar address:7960b824, val 1
lvar address:bf7bf314, val 1
```

since the addresses are distinct which means maybe it does not support virtual address.
Then I write another codes to test if it is really run simultaneously.
that is

in `a.cpp`: `print("a\n");` three times

in `b.cpp`: `print("b\n");` three times.

Then run `./a & ./b`, the result is

```
a
a
a
b
b
b
```

which means it runs `./a` first then runs `./b` hence those two programs do not run simultaneously.

Comment: In what way does it not work? Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: Reread the chapter - I think you have the context wrong. In no way will this probe "supports virtual address". Rather, use `sudo lshw -C cpu`

Comment: Does this mean virtual address is attribute of CPU?